# Is $(f,\mu)$ weakly mixing?

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I know how to show that if $(f,\mu)$ is weakly mixing then so is $(f^{k},\mu), \forall k \geq 2$. I was trying to proof the converse. I don't even know if this result is true and, at the end, seems to be a real analysis problem:

Fix $A$ and $B$ measurable sets. Define $a_{n}= |\int U^{n}_{f}(\mathbb{1}_{A}) \mathbb{1}_{B}d\mu-\mu(A)\mu(B)|$, where $U_{f}$ is the Koopman operator. By hypothesis, we have

$lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{jk}=0, \forall k\geq 2$.

Clearly, the question is if $lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}$ is equal to zero.

Maybe the last assertion is not true. Is there a known counterexample?

Comment: Could you please clarify your notation "$(f,\mu)$ is weakly mixing"?

Comment: As to your question if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^nb_j =0$ for a sequence $(b_n)$, any unbounded sequences like $b_n = n$ would provide a counterexample. The $(a_n)$ you define above for the sets $A$ and $B$ should however be more well-behaved.

Comment: Note that your counterexample $b_{n}=n$ does not satisfy the hypothesis.
Definition: We say that $(f,\mu)$ is weakly mixing if, for all measurable sets $A, B$, we have $lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} |\int U^{n}_{f}(\mathbb{1}_{A}) \mathbb{1}_{B}d\mu-\mu(A)\mu(B)|=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly the converse does hold. In fact you don't even need $T^k$ to be weakly mixing for *all* $k\geq 2$. A single one, such as $T^2$, will do. This is because a transformation $S$ being weak mixing is equivalent (See [Einsiedler and Ward](https://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9780857290205-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-989764-p174029173), theorem 2.36) to the following property:

> For any pair of measurable sets $A, B$, there is a zero [upper density
>   subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) of the naturals $E\subset \mathbb{N}$ such that $$ \lim\limits_{n\notin E, n\rightarrow \infty}  \mu(A\cap S^{-n}B) =
>  \mu(A)\mu(B). $$

Now assume this property holds for $S=T^2$ and consider the pair $A, B$ and the pair $A,T^{-1} B$. For the first pair, we get a zero-upper-density $E_0$ such that
$$\lim\limits_{n\notin E_0, n\rightarrow \infty}  \mu(A\cap T^{-2n}B) = \mu(A)\mu(B).
$$ From the second pair, we get a zero-upper-density $E_1$ such that
$$\lim\limits_{n\notin E_1, n\rightarrow \infty}  \mu(A\cap T^{-2n-1}B) = \mu(A)\mu(B).
$$

Together we have a zero-upper-density $E:=E_0\cup E_1$ which satisfies

$$\lim\limits_{n\notin E, n\rightarrow \infty}  \mu(A\cap T^{-n}B) = \mu(A)\mu(B).
$$

As an aside, this means that @mathworker12's interesting counterexample couldn't possibly arise as the quantities $|\int U^{n}_{f}(\mathbb{1}_{A}) \mathbb{1}_{B}d\mu-\mu(A)\mu(B)|$, for any measure preserving $f$.

Comment: +1 very nice...

Comment: hmm, I wonder how to prove $(a_n)_n = n^21_{prime}(n)$ can't arise in such a manner.

Comment: In fact. As a comment, I have just found another solution: A map $f$ is weakly mixing iff its Koopman Operator has $1$ as its only eigenvalue and the constant functions as its only eigenvectors. Suppose $U_{f}(g)=\lambda g$, then $U^{k}_{f}(g)=\lambda^{k} g$, so $\lambda^{k}=1 \forall k\geq 2$ implies $\lambda=1$ and $g$ is constant, that is, $(f,\mu)$ is weakly mixing

Comment: very nice! user25959 proved that $k=2$ is enough. for your solution, is there any way to rule out $\lambda = -1$ (just from $k=2$)?

Comment: @user25959 please see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

I provide a sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ of non-negative integers such that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n a_{jk} \to 0$ for each $k \ge 2$ but $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n a_j \not \to 0$. Let $a_n = n^2$ if $n$ is prime and $a_n = 0$ otherwise.

.

Actually, if the $a_n$'s are bounded, then the statement is true.

Claim: Let $(a_n)_n \ge 1$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $|a_n| \le 1$ for each $n$ and $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} a_{kn} \to 0$ for each $k \ge 2$. Then, $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} a_n \to 0$.

.

Proof: Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Take $m \ge 1$ so that $(1-\frac{1}{p_1})\dots(1-\frac{1}{p_m}) < \epsilon$. Then, $\sum_{d \mid p_1\dots p_m} \frac{\mu(d)}{d} = \frac{\phi(p_1\dots p_m)}{p_1 \dots p_m} < \epsilon$. For a positive integer $N$, the number of positive integers $n \le N$ not divisible by $p_1$ nor $p_2$ nor ... nor $p_m$ is $\sum_{d \mid p_1 \dots p_m} \mu(d)\lfloor \frac{N}{d} \rfloor = N\sum_{d \mid p_1 \dots p_m} \frac{\mu(d)}{d} + O(2^m) \le N\epsilon + O(2^m)$.

Fix a large positive integer $N$. For $d \ge 1$, let $A_d = \{n \le N : d \mid n\}$ and let $B = \{1,\dots,N\}\setminus(\cup_{j=1}^m A_{p_j})$. Then, $$\sum_{n \le N} a_n = \sum_{n \in B} a_n + \sum_{n \in \cup_j A_j} a_n = \sum_{n \in B} a_n- \sum_{\substack{d \mid p_1\dots p_m \\ d > 1}} \mu(d) \sum_{n \in A_d} a_n.$$ Therefore, noting that $|B| \le N\epsilon+O(2^m)$, we have $$\left|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} a_n\right| \le \epsilon+O(\frac{2^m}{N})+\sum_{\substack{d \mid p_1 \dots p_m \\ d > 1}} \frac{1}{d} \left|\frac{1}{N/d}\sum_{n \in A_d} a_n\right|$$ where by assumption $\frac{1}{N/d}\sum_{n \in A_d} a_n \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$ for each fixed $d$. As $m$ is fixed, the set of such $d$ is fixed and thus $$\limsup_{N \to \infty} \left|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} a_n\right| \le \epsilon.$$ As this holds for all $\epsilon > 0$, we are done.

Comment: Even though your counterexample works, I am handling with probability spaces, so $|a_{n}| \leq 2$. Also, the theorem from the other answer assumes to work in a probability space.

Comment: @Rhcpy99 please see my updated answer (which obviously holds if $|a_n| \le 1$ is replaced by $|a_n| \le 2$).